# ¿Existe alguna forma de poder ejecutar los oyentes/eventos desde el código?

Tags: java, java-awt

Me serviria saber alguna forma de poder ejecutar los eventos/oyentes de los componentes de java desde el codigo, asi como existe el método doClick() para el `JButton`, o alguna forma de poder hacer algo parecido sin tener que repetir todo el código que se encuentra en el oyente.

Comment: ya probaste con `addComponentListener()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addComponentListener(java.awt.event.ComponentListener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JButton` utiliza una interfaz al usar `addActionListener` y el método `doClick()` solo activa lo que escribiste en esa interfaz, si tu quieres hacer algo parecido para otros componentes podrías crear el tuyo también.

```
public interface ClickEvent {

    void click();

}
```

Luego tu componente debe tener 2 métodos uno para establecer el "evento" y otro para activarlo.

```
// Aquí es donde extiendes de tu componente, esto es una simulación
public class Componente { 

    private String name;
    private ClickEvent clickEvent;

    public Componente(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setEvent(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
        this.clickEvent = clickEvent;
    }

    public void doClick() {
        clickEvent.click();
    }

}
```

En la creación del componente harías algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Componente componente = new Componente("El gran componente");
    
    componente.setEvent(() -> {
        System.out.println("Se activo el evento.");
        System.out.println("El nombre es: " + componente.getName());
    });
    
    componente.doClick(); // Activa el evento escrito anteriormente
}
```

Esto es mas o menos lo que hace `JButton` cuando usas el método `addActionListener` que te pide una interfaz `ActionListener` como parámetro

```
JButton button = new JButton("El gran componente");

button.addActionListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("Se activo el evento.");
    System.out.println("El nombre es: " + button.getText());
});

button.doClick(); // Activa el evento del botón
```

Claro que JButton tiene una lista de eventos por eso el método te lo dice con `add` y no `set` como lo  hice yo, pero no seria difícil agregar una lista de eventos.

Ahora si tu quieres que al presionar un componente realice la acción dada, simplemente agrégale un `mouseClicked` de `MouseAdapter` y llama al método `doClick` que creaste para activar la interfaz.

Espero te sirva, no se si era lo que esperabas.

Comment: Gracias no se me había ocurrido hacerlo de esa forma, aunque no es exactamente lo que esperaba,  al hacerlo de esa manera para cada componete que quiero que tenga esa función, tengo que crear una clase que extienda del mismo y agregarle asi lo necesario para que ande la función, lo cual es un poco engorroso, pero de todas maneras me sirvio.

Comment: Sí, de hecho JButton y JToggleButton extienden de AbstractButton, este a la vez extiende de JComponent y tiene el método ``doClick()``, los otras clases al extender de AbstractButton le permite ser componentes y ademas tener todos los métodos de esta (doClick, getIcon, addActionListener y otros). En otras palabras las demás clases de tipo botón solo se preocupan por extender de AbstractButton y tienen el pase libre para crear y crear componentes.